# Cannot remove lsb-release package

Tags: apt, package-management, python, lsb-release

I was trying to install nodejs via

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
```

but ran into a problem "no module named lsb_release". After reading trought the internet for some time, I found out that its a python related file and makes mess when more than one version of python are installed. So I (a linux noob) decided to uninstall both python and python2.7 and reinstall it later, however. As I am trying to uninstall python, I run into this:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lsb-release : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
```

So I tried to `apt-get remove lsb-release` which prints the same error. I cannot reinstall python2.7 either, any suggestions please?